# html tag thead effect javascript to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table. The items in the thead contains one checkbox. If I click the check box "selectAll" it checks all the checkboxes in the table. I had to add jquery tablesorter. For that purpose I had to use `thead`. My javascript stopped working because of thead. If I remove thead it works fine and clicking the checkbox checks all the other checkboxes in the table.

My html is:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="idCheckBox"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/> All</th>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<th id="idEsc">Column 4</th>
<th>Column 5</th>
<th id="idComments">Column 6</th>
<th id="idSuspend">Column 7</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

My java script function is:

```
$( function() {
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectAll").click( function() {
        $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(".case").click( function() {

        if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectAll").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectAll").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Any gurus out there for help?

Cheers

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7hdGW/1/ I don't think it is because of `thead`, use `.prop()` to set the checked property

Comment: also what is the jQuery version used

Comment: _"My javascript stopped working because of thead."_ Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: It's jquery-1.8.1.min.js. I get this in Console "[15:41:26.371] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: @KingKhan did you check the solution I gave... is it working

Comment: @Arun. It's working in fiddle. But I have a <c:forEach in <tbody> and that is why I have a list of checkboxes. I assume plain html may work. But I have different html.

Comment: @Arun P Johny I tried the latest jquery as well but I get this error in Console "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead." If I remove thead everything works fine.

Comment: @KingKhan that is a warning.... so that is fine..... can you share the generated html

Comment: @KingKhan also whether the elements are created after dom ready event like using ajax

Comment: @KingKhan another test case you can add is to replace the `<c:forEach` with few rows of static elements and see what is happening

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have removed the `<c:forEach` and replaced it with static elements. I have simplified my html as well. Still facing the same problem. If I remove `thead` it works fine. How can I share generated html? It's too long to write here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is because of `thead`. Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to set the checked property value

```
$(function () {
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectAll").click(function () {
        $cases.prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    var $cases = $(".case").click(function () {
        $("#selectAll").prop("checked", $cases.not(':checked').length == 0);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7hdGW/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a function name in the javascript and by calling it on `onclick` event of checkbox.

My html is:

```
<th id="idCheckBox"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="selectCheckBoxes()"/> All</th>
```

and java script:

```
function selectCheckBoxes(){
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectAll").click( function() {
        $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(".case").click( function() {

        if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectAll").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectAll").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
};
```